# ByteBuddy: Use new defined field in intercept during construction of class

Tags: java, subclassing, byte-buddy

I am looking at some ByteBuddy code from someone else. He uses ByteBuddy to generate runtime subclasses which are used as proxies to implement some management code of his runtime into specific objects.

```
Class<? extends T> newSubClass = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.ofThisVm())
                .subclass(classType)
                .defineField("_core", Object.class, Visibility.PUBLIC) //<---
                .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(classType))
                .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of((proxy, method, m_args) -> {
                    //TODO: Need to replace core with _core as core is a function argument and will make it bound
                    return proxyHandler(core, method, m_args); //<--
                }))
                .make()
                .load(roleType.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded();


T proxy = ReflectionHelper.newInstance(newSubClass, args);
newSubClass.getField("_core").set(proxy, core);
```

In order to not bind the `core` object directly into the lambda I want to use the new defined field `_core`so I can reuse the generated class (and not regenerate it for every call of the function).
 Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can define custom constructors just as you define methods. One important point for defining a constructor is that you require another constructor call as its first instruction. You can invoke a constructor using `MethodCall::invoke` which you can combine with `FieldAccessor::ofField`.

This way, you can define your class similar to the following:

```
new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.ofThisVm())
  .subclass(classType, ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
  .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .withParameter(InvocationHandler.class)
    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(classType.getDeclaredConstructor())
    .andThen(FieldAccessor.ofField("_core").setsArgumentAt(0)))
  .defineField("_core", InvocationHandler.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(classType))
    .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.toField("_core"))
  .make();
```

This way, you can set a custom `InvocationHandler` per instance. If you want to only store the state in the `_core` field and access this field from your interceptor, have a look at `MethodDelegation`:

```
new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.ofThisVm())
  .subclass(classType, ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
  .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .withParameter(Object.class)
    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(classType.getDeclaredConstructor())
    .andThen(FieldAccessor.ofField("_core").setsArgumentAt(0)))
  .defineField("_core", Object.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(classType))
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyHandler.class))
  .make();

public class MyHandler {
  @RuntimeType
  public static Object intercept(@FieldValue("_core") Object value) { ... }
}
```

Other annotations you might need are `@This`, `@AllArguments`, `@Origin` and `@SuperCall`. The less you need, the more efficient your proxy will be. Especially `@AllArguments` is expensive due to its allocation requirements.

Note that in this case, your field is only set after the super constructor call. Also, you assume that there is a default constructor in the super type. Alternatively, you can implement a custom `ConstructorStrategy`.

As for caching, have a look at Byte Buddy's `TypeCache`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint w.r.t. caching. I would have used a `WeakHashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>` else.

Comment: That would not work as the value is a subclass of the key and references it strongly. Rather use the `TypeCache` which works around this by also referencing the value softly or weakly.

Comment: It is still not clear to me how I could access the new `_core` argument in the `.intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of((proxy, method, m_args) -> proxyHandler(core, method, m_args);`

Comment: Did you not want to delegate to an invocation handler that is stored in `_core`? In this case, have a look at the `MethodDelegation` implementation. In this class, you can access properties via the `@FieldValue("_core")` annotation. See my updated answer.